# jQuery - Allow user to add a maximum of 4 divs/user inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to emulate this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tzpg4/4/) (code also shown below) and modify it to allow user to add a maximum of 4 fields

JS:

```
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

HTML:

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Additionally, I tried reworking and updating code for the latest version of jQuery 1.11.0, updating function, `.live()` to `.on()` and `.size()` to `.length()` per jQuery documentation, but no luck...code didn't work that way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you try this? http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/13615/

Comment: If you add max fields and then try removing you can't add fields. Thanks for the help!

Comment: i did that. check the latest fiddle

Comment: Looks good, just need to update the jQuery for ver 1.11.0

Comment: yeah. if you're updating it to the latest version you can use 'on' instead of 'live'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers. Also, replace ID with class because there will be multiple input elements.

You can use the property [**.length**](https://api.jquery.com/length/) to get the count of elements

In order to delete, you have to *delegate* the events since the remove anchor tag will be added dynamically to the DOM. Like this `$('#p_scents').on('click','.remScnt', function(){ });`

This works with `jQuery 1.10.1`

Overall, something like this should do.

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('.p_scnt').length;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function () {
        if (i >= 4) return;
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
    });

    $('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function () {
        if (i > 0) {
            $(this).closest('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/tZPg4/13620/**

---

Also you can improve the add functionality to something like for a cleaner code

```
$('#addScnt').on('click', function () {
    if (i >= 4) return;
    var newInput = $('<input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" placeholder="Input value" />');
    var removeLink = $('<a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>');
    var newEl = $('<p></p>').append(newInput).append(removeLink);
    newEl.appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Looks like once you add max fields and remove, you can remove all but two fields.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to replace `>2` with `>0`.